# Foreign Key Duplication?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Probably a simple answer here, I hope, but seems like a difficult question to put into words.

If you have a Foreign Key that essentially appears twice in a table, coming from two Composite Keys does that FK then have to be defined twice (exist as two separate attributes)?

Here are some **simple** models to visualize what I am asking.  Ex. 1 shows the FK of Table1Id as a single attribute.  Ex. 2 shows the FK of Table1Id (identified as Table1Id_FKTable2 & Table1Id_FKTable3) as two different attributes.

Depending on what you want to accomplish are both of these models valid? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the `table1ID_FKTable2` is better called a "role" that Table1 plays with respect to Table4.

And similarly, `table1ID_FKTable3` is a different "role" that Table1 plays with respect to Table4.

The idea of role is pervasive.  Two employees belong to the same company, but may have different roles, one as member of the board of directors, the other as part-time, hourly.

Comment: I made these models by changing the Role in my modeling program.  I did admit it is hard for me to put this question into words...hehe.  Ok so do you have to split the Roles up and define them both as Ex.2 shows or can that Role be the same and exist as Ex. 1?

Comment: @swisscheese: I reference the names from example 2 because those explicitly state the role.  You can't optimize the roles out of existence.  If it's part of the problem, you must keep them.  Example 2 is a *different* model from Example 1.  And Example 2 is correct **if** you have to distinct roles.

Comment: Great thanks for the help.  In working with a DB model where the composite keys were getting quite lengthy this question arose.  I think I need to look back at the relevance of my composite keys.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your question, but if the primary key of Table2 is a composite of Table1Id and Table2Id then you need to create a foreign key from Table4 using both fields. Same thing for Table3.

```
ALTER TABLE Table4 ADD constraint fk_tab2 foreign key references Table2(Table1Id, Table2Id)
ALTER TABLE Table4 ADD constraint fk_tab3 foreign key references Table3(Table1Id, Table3Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your drawings do not "visualise what you are asking", because your drawings do not appear to contain any composite keys at all.

But if your question is (something like) "Can one single attribute in table4 be declared to be a foreign key *BOTH* into table2 and table3 ?", then the answer is yes.

It would be unlikely if it worked the way you'd want it to if you use ID fields all over the place, but neither the relational model nor even the SQL standard prevent it.

Comment: I emphasized the word simple in my question as to hopefully avoid knocks at my terminology (which when it comes to DBs I am still learning, hence the disclosures in my question).  Unless you know my data you can't say that Id is just a dummy term or surrogate key or not.  Just to continue your point why didn't you point out that I shouldn't name all my tables Table?